# "Entscheiden" as reflexive verb?

Tags: difference, verb, reflexive

Which of the following are correct?

> (a) Ich habe entschieden, am Wochenende nach Moskau zu reisen.
>
> (b) Ich habe mich entschieden, am Wochenende nach Moskau zu reisen.
>
> (c) Ich habe mir entschieden, am Wochenende nach Moskau zu reisen.

If more than one, are the any differences in meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version a) and b) are correct and they mean the same. Version b) might have a little more personal touch than a) which sounds a bit "businessy".

Version a) is the only possible construction if you decide a "direct object", as in

> Ich entscheide etwas.

Also, if you decide something that concerns only others you cannot really use the "mich" version. That might be the case if you're the boss in a company or something

> Ich habe entschieden, dass Matthias das Projekt übernimmt.

This is especially so, once you put the whole thing in third person

> Er hat sich entschieden, nach Rom zu fahren... ist ok
>
> Er hat sich entschieden, dass Thomas nach Rom fährt.... ist nicht ok

Version c) is always wrong but might be heard in Berlin dialect.